# Expressing 2nd derivative of f(g(x)) in terms of f (rather than in terms of 1st derivative)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there an expression of the 2nd derivative of $f(g(x))$ that also involves $f$, as opposed to merely $f'$, $f''$?

I have the first derivative as:

$$f'(g(x))(g'(x))$$

and the second as:

$$f'(g(x))(g''(x)) + f''(g(x))(g'(x))(g'(x))$$

Yet I am asked to find this second derivative in terms including $f$. It seems to me that $f$ should not feature in the expression for the *first* derivative, let alone the second.

Have I ignored something simple?

Comment: Paradoxical.. Are you talking about syntax/notation where $f$ without tags appears? Or do you just not want to differentiate? Or, add and subtract it... Or, if it was a multiplication of functions to begin with, then $f$ would have appeared, or if it was $e^{g}$ :D

Comment: Thanks @Dror. I *do* want to differentiate, and I am wondering whether it is possible to express the second derivative in terms of $f$ without tags, i.e. in terms of the original function $f$ (as well as in terms of the other components, $g$, $g'$, $f'$, etc.) Does this make any sense?

Comment: Still ambigous.. So many answers: 1. There are some concrete functions that go back to what you started with after the 2nd differentiation but obviously not all. 2. *expression* has many notations, but one meaning mostly: the tag stands for you did derivative. Have you not? Did I get it? :)

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this very clearly. 1. For the purposes of the question, it is immaterial what the functions $f$ or $g$ could be, but we consider these functions able to be differentiated at every possible $x$. 2. When I say *expression*, I simply mean *a way of writing/notating*. In terms of the tag, yes, I write $f'$ to mean *the derivative of* $f$. So I have differentiated the original expression twice, but it seems to me the second derivative *cannot* be written so as to include the original $f$ (i.e. the undifferentiated function), which is what I am asked to do.

Comment: $f$ is *the* root here so in tag notation it will not appear without tags. Either you denote you plan to do it by: $(f \circ g)''$, or Leibniz notation

Comment: Thank you @Dror, this is what I suspected. I did not see how $f$ could appear in the second derivative in its undifferentiated form. I believe the question may be poorly worded.

Comment: And I'm not sure I got the right expression, but you get the idea

Comment: Is this homework assignment?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58113/discussion-between-remnant-and-dror).